TIDA-01513 Isolation Card Riso Calculation
Vref: 2.53V
iso_neg: 3V
batt_voltage: 100V

I am trying to calculate the Riso resistance using these equations, but I am getting unreliable results. When I rearrange the equation to isolate Riso, it becomes:(((batt_voltage + 2.53) * 5110 + 2.53 * 1200000 + 2.53 * 10000 - iso_neg_voltage * 1200000 - iso_neg_voltage * 10000) / (iso_neg_voltage - 2.53)); However, this doesn't seem to work, and I don't know why. Also, I have seen this equation in forums and tried it:

But its also doesnt work what is these variables unit, where I'am doing mistake.
